# Why is the ll in Medellín and la mejilla pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciación, letras

I hear the ll as ʝ in "Medellín" and ʎ in "mejilla".

It is on the first minute of these clips:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8QaOFiFDps
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzbWimMb_7Y

Comment: Maybe lleísmo and/or [yeísmo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2432/5481)?

Comment: In the first minute of these clips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8QaOFiFDps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzbWimMb_7Y

Comment: Those are two different speakers in those videos - they have different accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't hear [ʎ] in either of the videos. I hear a voiced fricative [ʝ] in "mejillas" (which tends to become an approximant [j]) for the first few speakers in the second video (who are... Colombian?).

For "Medellín", the speaker (which speaks standard European Spanish) alternates between a fricative that sounds very close to [ʒ] and its corresponding affricate [dʒ]. I believe this alternation is common, especially when the syllable is stressed.

The sound transcribed as *ll* is only rarely a true palatal lateral, and it varies a lot among dialects and even among individuals. Since there are no similar sounds in Spanish that could be mistaken for it, this variation often goes unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

It would normally be a case of different speakers, different accents. But the fact that the first speaker is speaking with a Spanish (from Spain) accent suggests that this is a case of a foreign speaker pronouncing Medellín in the local manner.